# Remove Duplicate rows from a large table - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from a large table having about 1million rows and increasing every hour. It has no unique id and has about ~575 columns but sparsely filled.

The table is 'like' a log table where new entries are appended every hour without unique timestamp.

The duplicates are like 1-3% but I want to remove it anyway ;) Any ideas?

I tried ctid column (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-completely-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql-and-keep-only-1)) but its very slow.

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea that works generally well with PostgreSQL is to create an index on the hash of the set of columns as a whole.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON tablename (md5((tablename.*)::text));
```

This will work unless there are columns that don't play well with the requirement of immutability (mostly `timestamp with time zone` because their cast-to-text value is session-dependent).

Once this index is created, duplicates can be found quickly by self-joining with the hash, with a query looking like this:

```
SELECT t1.ctid, t2.ctid
FROM tablename t1 JOIN tablename t2
 ON (md5((t1.*)::text) = md5((t2.*)::text))
WHERE t1.ctid > t2.ctid;
```

You may also use this index to avoid duplicates rows in the future rather than periodically de-duplicating them, by making it UNIQUE (duplicate rows would be rejected at INSERT or UPDATE time).

Comment: Didn't work for me, since I have timestamps with TZ, but I like the approach.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but with a timestamptz. However I know for a fact that the database is UTC and (obviously) so are the timestamps; I'm looking for a workaround to immutability. I want to nuke a few thousand duplicate rows out of millions of rows so I can recreate the primary key...

Comment: @Jeff: if you have a candidate primary key then you don't need the above method. Create an index on it, then eliminate the duplicates with a self-join that presumably will use that index, then drop the index, then set the unique constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! I will try a few things, otherwise I'll create a new question here and let you know.

Comment: @DanielVérité Correct me if im wrong but in the example you've given here the index is created on all columns right? how can I do the same thing but create the md5 index only on specific columns?

Comment: @OmriShneor: this answer appears to be obsolete and if you need to deduplicate only on some columns, that's not the same question anyway. Please submit a new question.

Comment: @DanielVérité why is the answer obsolete?

Comment: @OmriShneor: because PG says that `tablename.*::text` is not immutable no matter what the structure and refuses to create the index on `md5(tablename.*::text)`. This needs to be worked around.