# Postgres Remove records by duplicate control_id

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I'll preface with the join's and examples that were similar found, I could not get to work and i appreciate any help.
I have postgres 9.X table with a few columns:
datetime|control_id|content|

How do I remove additional records that have the same control_id?  I do not care about which record's datetime and content is kept as the content will be duplicate, but the datetime is unique (it does not matter which datetime is kept).  eg

**Input may look like:**

```
01012015|333|blahblah
01042014|333|blahblah
02032015|333|blahblah
10102014|388|bleehbleeh
11112014|388|bleehbleeh
```

**Output I want:**

```
01012015|333|blahblah
10102014|388|bleehbleeh
```

Any date can be in the output as long as the control_id column only exists once.  A select distinct didn't work for me as the datetime column is unique.

Comment: Do you want to delete those rows _permanently_ or just filter them out in a SELECT query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-completely-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql-and-keep-only-1

Comment: They can be deleted.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I did not realize ctid was for that or that it existed.  Worked like a charm.