# PostgreSQL 9.4 Insert data from backup file into the table with UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I've seen a lot of similar topics, but no any clear solution.

What i have:
Production DB on Amazon RDS. I need to restore/input data to one of the tables in that DB from the dump (.backup) located on my PC.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE condos
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  latitude numeric,
  longtitude numeric,
  condo_id serial NOT NULL,
  city text NOT NULL,
  country text NOT NULL,
  address text,
  district text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_condo_id PRIMARY KEY (condo_id),
  CONSTRAINT uniq_title UNIQUE (name)
)
```

**The problem:** once i'm trying to restore it from local DB, i get a UNIQUE constraint violation error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "condos": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_condo_id"
DETAIL:  Key (condo_id)=(21) already exists.
```

Also, there are other tables have relations with the table `condos` and i don't want to update whole DB.

I know that it's not the first time i'm going to do this procedure,so my question is - what is the **best & simple way to update the table** and input the data into it (only the data which is not exists in the production DB's table)?

Comment: Restore data into the another schema, then update your production data from it using SQLs (just one solution from the many possible).

Comment: ' best & simple way to update the table'

Comment: I suspect your `SERIAL` column is causing complications. Can you change it to an integer type for the import, and then reattach it to the sequence afterwards?

Comment: is there any reason of changing it to other time except this merging issue? I mean, from what i see, `SERIAL` usually used for indexing

Comment: `SERIAL` isn't a real type, it's a shortcut for integer defaulting to using a sequence. [The documentation on it is here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). Since they are equivalent, you should be able re-add the `DEFAULT nextval(...)` after your import ([though you'll likely want to use `setval` afterwards](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and best may not always be the same.

### Insert via a temporary table

Create another table similar to the one you have let us name it `condos_tmp`. Import your data into this table. Assuming your dump does not have duplicate entries the import will be successful. Then do:

```
DELETE FROM condos_tmp WHERE condo_id in (SELECT condo_id FROM condos)
```

Note that this query will take a very long time if you have millions of records. Next it's a simple insert select

```
INSERT INTO condos SELECT * FROM condos_tmp
```

### By dropping the keys and then deleting duplicates

This solution can be used even if your dump has duplicate data.

```
ALTER TABLE condos DROP CONSTRAINT pk_condo_id;
ALTER TABLE condos DROP CONSTRAINT uniq_title;
```

Now import your data. Then hunt for duplicates. Refer https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates and [Delete completely duplicate rows in PostgreSQL (and keep only 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-completely-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql-and-keep-only-1) the decision on which one to delete is upto you. These links explain how you can write your query for each situation.

Then add back the constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE condos ADD CONSTRAINT pk_condo_id PRIMARY KEY(condo_id);
ALTER TABLE condos ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_title UNIQUE(uniq_title);
```