# How to remove duplicate value from a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataset like:

```
order_id | order_item_id | category
1        | 1             | book
1        | 2             | pen
1        | 3             | book
```

now I have to remove the `order_item_id` and its row that has duplicate value on category columns but still leave 1 of them. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by "duplicate value"?

Comment: Duplicate of [Delete Duplicate Records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-records-in-postgresql)

Comment: @NicoHaase duplicate value means there are some category values that same in 1 order id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete if there is a row with the same `order_id` and `category` but with less `order_item_id`:

```
delete from orders o
where exists (
  select 1 
  from orders 
  where 
    orders.order_id = o.order_id
    and
    orders.category = o.category
    and 
    orders.order_item_id < o.order_item_id
  );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=ebc470a1dcbe10204cf3dc3989f85844)

Comment: Sorry im new, how to accept the answer? I can't upvote it :(

Answer (score 0):

delete from mytable where order_item_id not in (select max(order_item_id) from mytable group by order_ID,category)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
delete from t
    where t.order_item_id > (select min(t2.order_item_id)
                             from t t2
                             where t2.order_id = t.order_id and
                                   t2.category = t.category
                            );
```