# Python PostgreSQL drop duplicate rows

Tags: python, postgresql

I have `python 3.7.3`, `psycopg2 version '2.7.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'`, and `PostGreSQL version 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)` installed.

The below [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963112/988125) works from the terminal and does indeed delete all duplicate rows by column: `id` in table: `mydbschema.table1`.

```
DELETE  FROM  mydbschema.table1  a  USING( SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, id FROM mydbschema.table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.ctid <> b.ctid;
```

However, when I want to run it through a python connection and cursor, the deletion does not happen.

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect(user=conn_details['user'],
                              password=conn_details['password'],
                              host=conn_details['host'],
                              port=conn_details['port'],
                              database=conn_details['database'])
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("DELETE  FROM  mydbschema.table1  a  USING( SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, id FROM mydbschema.table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.ctid <> b.ctid;")
 cursor.close()
```

I know the problem is not due to the `connection`, as the below subsection of the query works completely fine:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, id FROM mydbschema.table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;")
cursor.fetchall()
Out[3]: [('(0,3)', 3), ('(0,4)', 4), ('(0,2)', 2)]
```

Am I missing something? Is `cursor.execute()` not suitable for this type of deletion command?

Comment: are you forgetting to `commit` your query? your cursor might not be in auto-commit mode

Comment: @aws_apprentice The subsection of the query (at the bottom of the question) returns results, would I additionally need to manually do a `commit` step for the full deletion query above?

Comment: I would `commit` your query before closing the first connection

Comment: Indeed, it worked!. I did not realise for database changes to persist you needde to commit.  Can you write a short answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `commit` your `DELETE` query in your first connection prior to running a subsequent query in a new connection to see the results reflected. You can see [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit)
that the cursor is *not* opened in auto-commit mode so a manual `commit` is required. Conversely you can open the cursor in auto-commit as noted in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You must use commit() method to persist the delete command:

```
import psycopg2
connection =psycopg2.connect(user=conn_details['user'],
                          password=conn_details['password'],
                          host=conn_details['host'],
                          port=conn_details['port'],
                          database=conn_details['database'])
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE  FROM  mydbschema.table1  a  
USING( SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, id FROM 
mydbschema.table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.ctid <> b.ctid;")
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```