# How can I remove rows that are 100% duplicates in a PostgreSQL table without a primary key?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a PostgreSQL table with a very large number of columns. The table does not have a primary key and now contains several rows that are 100% duplicates of another row.

**How can I remove those duplicates without deleting the original along with them?**

I found this answer on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584134/484293), but I'd have to spell out each and every column name, which is error-prone. **How can I avoid having to know anything about the table structure?**

**Example:**

Given

```
create table duplicated (
 id int,
 name text,
 description text
);

insert into duplicated
values (1, 'A', null), 
       (2, 'B', null),
       (2, 'B', null),
       (3, 'C', null), 
       (3, 'C', null), 
       (3, 'C', 'not a DUPE!');
```

after deletion, the following rows should remain:

```
(1, 'A', null) 
(2, 'B', null)
(3, 'C', null) 
(3, 'C', 'not a DUPE!')
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: edited my question to explain the difference to the question you proposed as duplicate: one aspect I couldn't find there was how to avoid knowing the table structure. This rendered its answer inapplicable in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584134/484293), use the [system column `ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-system-columns.html) to distinguish the physical copies of otherwise indentical rows.

To avoid having to spell out a non-existing 'key' for the rows, simply use the [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) `row(table)`, which returns a 
row value containing the entire row as returned by `select * from table`:

```
DELETE FROM duplicated
USING (
      SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, row(duplicated) as row
        FROM duplicated 
        GROUP BY row(duplicated) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) uniqued
      WHERE row(duplicated) = uniqued.row
      AND duplicated.ctid <> uniqued.ctid;
```

You can try it in this [DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ff95085214570b1dcd336a77c47d6600).