# Add Column in table with value partition by group

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

My table is somethingg like

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    _id         text,
    name        text,
    data_type   int,
    data_value  int,
    data_date   timestamp -- insertion time
);
```

Now due to a system bug, many duplicate entries are created and I need to remove those duplicated and keep only unique entries excluding data_date because it is a system generated date.

My query to do that is something like:

```
DELETE FROM table1 A
USING ( SELECT _id, name, data_type, data_value, MIN(data_date) min_date
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY _id, name, data_type, data_value
        HAVING count(data_date) > 1) B
WHERE A._id = B._id
AND A.name = B.name
AND A.data_type = B.data_type
AND A.data_value = B.data_value
AND A.data_date != B.min_date;
```

However this query works, having millions of records in the table, I want a faster way for it. My idea is to create a new column with value as partition by [_id, name, data_type, data_value] or columns which are in group by. However, I could not find the way to create such column.
I would appretiate if any one may suggest a way to create such column.

**Edit 1:**
There is another thing to add, I don't want to use CTE or subquery for updating this new column because it will be same as my existing query.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is simply creating a new table without duplicated records:

```
CREATE...
SELECT _id, name, data_type, data_value, MIN(data_date) min_date
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY _id, name, data_type, data_value;
```

Alternatively, you can create a rank and then filter, but a subquery is needed.

`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY your_variables ORDER BY data_date ASC) r`

And then filter r=1.

Comment: Having a duplicate table with millions of doesn't seems to be a good idea. This will take a lot of time creating. I actually tried that and took around 25 mins or so. The server was almost dead for that time. Can't block my production server for that long.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-records-in-postgresql

Comment: alternatively you could speed up your query.

Comment: I would want to speed-up but not sure how to do that

Comment: Maybe use DISTINCT ON, or joins with HASH() or even use ANTI JOIN.

Comment: Then maybe the best thing to do is try to debug duplicates from its origin.