# How can I delete rows that are duplicated on some columns?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have the following table:

```
Id    color    size
1     blue     medium
2     blue     medium
3     blue     small
4     red      big
```

I to exclude all rows that have the color and size duplicated, but different Id. But bear in mind that I don't want to keep one of them, I want to exclude both that have color and size similar, but Id different. So this would be my final table:

```
Id    color    size
3     blue     small
4     red      big
```

I found this post [Delete Duplicate Records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-records-in-postgresql) and this one https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/. But both of them want to keep one of the rows. I don't want it.

Is there any way?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `2, blue, medium` in the results?

Comment: Where does `(3, red, medium)` come from? It's not in the original data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are absolutely right, so sorry. Just fixed

Comment: @forpas yes, I want it

Comment: There is no `(3, red, big)` either

Comment: Why? Rows with ids 1 and 2 are duplicates.

Comment: @forpas sorry guys, I did everything wrong, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename 
  where id <> t.id and color = t.color and size = t.size
);
```

or with `COUNT()` window function:

```
select t.Id, t.color, t.size
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by color, size) counter
  from tablename
) t  
where t.counter = 1
```

If you want to delete the duplicate rows from the table then:

```
delete from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename 
  where id <> t.id and color = t.color and size = t.size
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e2c3f067f87d3edb50aacf44e69686a).
Results:

```
| id  | color | size  |
| --- | ----- | ----- |
| 3   | blue  | small |
| 4   | red   | big   |
```