# How to delete duplicate row in table ?(Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

Here my table :

```
img_id | tag_id
   1        2
   1        2
   1        4
   3        4
   3        5
```

and i want to :

```
img_id | tag_id
   1        2
   1        4
   3        4
   3        5
```

Please help me ! Tks

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-records-in-postgresql

Comment: Try not to create it in the first place, which is much easier.