# SQL Delete duplicate records based on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

In postgresql

I need a lookup table to have unique values in two column. I have this list of cars but Golf is duplicated on Car and Shop columns. I want to remove all records where car and shop are the same (because horsepower and KM will be the same)

[image: Input table]

So the output table should be:

[image: desired output]

Thanks!!

Comment: please tag with database platform.  Sounds like you also need to add the proper integrity constraints such as a primary key or uniqueness index to prevent future duplicates

Comment: It is really just for a temporary lookup table, but once duplicates are removed primary key would be car and shop

Comment: You can identify duplicates with a query, but to remove all but one you'll probably need to run a procedure with a cursor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate rows from small table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-rows-from-small-table)

Comment: @Johnny duplicate value based on car, shop, horsepower and KM or (car and shop)

Comment: @Johnny And in your given sample car = leon and shop = Madrid..but your output column shop will madrid and barcelona for loan. I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (car, shop) t.*
from t
order by car, shop, day;
```

If you want to actually delete the records:

```
delete from t
   where t.day = (select min(t2.day)
                  from t2
                  where t2.car = t.car and t2.shop = t.shop
                 );
```