# Keep only first row given a set of columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | creation_date | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 April | a | b | e |
| 2 | 23 April | a | b | e |
| 3 | 21 April | c | d | e |

My goal is to **delete all the duplicates**, **keeping only the first (ie first created)** row.

The duplicates are defined using a set of columns from the table. For example, using col1 and col2, the result will be :

| id | creation_date | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 April | a | b | e |
| 3 | 21 April | c | d | e |

One answer that I found use [one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-rows-from-small-table/45606037#45606037) as a key :

```sql
DELETE FROM dups a USING (
      SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, key
        FROM dups 
        GROUP BY key HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) b
      WHERE a.key = b.key 
      AND a.ctid <> b.ctid
```

, but I can't see how to adapt to the case where multiple columns are used, and where the earliest record should be kept.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `DELETE` and `EXISTS` with your logic in subquery condition.

```
DELETE 
FROM dups t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM dups tt
               WHERE tt.col1 =  t.col1
               AND tt.col2 =  t.col2
               AND tt.col3 =  t.col3
               HAVING MIN(tt.ctid) <> t.ctid
               );
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af50e518056ae0f394b221028d55da63)

Comment: You can replace the HAVING clause with `AND tt.ctid < t.ctid`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit self join of the table:

```
DELETE FROM dups d1
USING dups d2
WHERE (d2.col1, d2.col2, d2.col3) = (d1.col1, d1.col2, d1.col3)
  AND d2.creation_date < d1.creation_date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0f463a47a8af4f11b36292453fd6482).