# Find and delete duplicate rows with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, duplicates, postgresql-9.2

We have a table of photos with the following columns:

```
id, merchant_id, url
```

this table contains duplicate values for the combination `merchant_id, url`. so it's possible that one row appears more several times.

```
234 some_merchant  http://www.some-image-url.com/abscde1213
235 some_merchant  http://www.some-image-url.com/abscde1213
236 some_merchant  http://www.some-image-url.com/abscde1213
```

What is the best way to delete those duplications?
(I use PostgreSQL 9.2 and Rails 3.)

Comment: Is your ID column unique?  I see 234 3 times but you say your merchant_id and url are the duplicate values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries-in-postgresql

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the id in the example above should be unique. thanks for the correct edit. the solution here stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/… doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Here is my take on it.

```
select * from (
  SELECT id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY merchant_Id, url ORDER BY id asc) AS Row
  FROM Photos
) dups
where 
dups.Row > 1
```

Feel free to play with the order by to tailor the records you want to delete to your specification.

SQL Fiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6941/1/0

---

SQL Fiddle for Postgres 9.2 is no longer supported; updating SQL Fiddle to postgres 9.3

Comment: This works like a charm but how do you delete the duplicates found using this query ?

Comment: If we have same thing repeating 3 times, the take 2 and take 3 is taken in result. How can i resolve it?

Comment: It's a bit unclear about what you are trying to do; the answer provided shows, using the sql fiddle link, how to delete rows based on columns defined. 

You should probably open up a new question with specific steps to reproduce.

Comment: Could you explain what it is actually doing by 

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY merchant_Id, url ORDER BY id asc)`

Comment: won't this delete all records with the duplicate id's? I think de OP wants to keep one record in

Comment: No it will not, that's precisely why you check rows > 1.  See the sql fiddle.

Comment: As a non db guy I found this explanationa really good https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Comment: to delete rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6941/983

Answer (score 10):

The second part of sgeddes's answer doesn't work on Postgres (the fiddle uses MySQL). Here is an updated version of his answer using Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6b1a7/1

```
DELETE FROM Photos AS P1  
USING Photos AS P2
WHERE P1.id > P2.id
   AND P1.merchant_id = P2.merchant_id  
   AND P1.url = P2.url;
```

Answer (score 6):

I see a couple of options for you.

For a quick way of doing it, use something like this (it assumes your ID column is not unique as you mention 234 multiple times above):

```
CREATE TABLE tmpPhotos AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Photos;
DROP TABLE Photos;
ALTER TABLE tmpPhotos RENAME TO Photos;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e945/1).

You will need to add your constraints back to the table if you have any.

If your ID column is unique, you could do something like to keep your lowest id:

```
DELETE FROM P1  
USING Photos P1, Photos P2
WHERE P1.id > P2.id
   AND P1.merchant_id = P2.merchant_id  
   AND P1.url = P2.url;
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83864/1).

Comment: the id is unique in my case. I just did it wrong in my example code. but I get an error if I try to use your second solution. `ERROR:  relation "p1" does not exist`

Comment: @StefanSchmidt I fixed it to run on Postgres instead of MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6b1a7/1