# How to find duplicate records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a PostgreSQL database table called "user_links" which currently allows the following duplicate fields:

```
year, user_id, sid, cid
```

The unique constraint is currently the first field called "id", however I am now looking to add a constraint to make sure the `year`, `user_id`, `sid` and `cid` are all unique but I cannot apply the constraint because duplicate values already exist which violate this constraint.

Is there a way to find all duplicates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find duplicate rows with PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471179/find-duplicate-rows-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 649, accepted):

The basic idea will be using a nested query with count aggregation:

```
select * from yourTable ou
where (select count(*) from yourTable inr
where inr.sid = ou.sid) > 1
```

You can adjust the where clause in the inner query to narrow the search.

---

There is another good solution for that mentioned in the comments, (but not everyone reads them):

```
select Column1, Column2, count(*)
from yourTable
group by Column1, Column2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Or shorter:

```
SELECT (yourTable.*)::text, count(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY yourTable.*
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: You could also use HAVING: `select co1, col2, count(*) from tbl group by col1, col2 HAVING count(*)>1`

Comment: Thanks @alexkovelsky the having statement was easier to modify for me and ran quicker. I would suggest an answer with it for higher visibility.

Comment: these options worked to me, the others groups the results, and these options gave me all the duplicated records instead of just the record duplicated, thanks!

Comment: I have your this answer to be a bit slow. On a table 10k rows * 18 columns, the query took 8 seconds

Comment: why does the query work with `yourTable.*`, but not with `*` only?

Comment: The first option takes too much to load... select Column1, Column2, count(*)
from yourTable
group by Column1, Column2
HAVING count(*) > 1
Worked instantly.

Comment: It seems to me too that the "another good solution" works seriously faster.

Comment: The second solution is much faster, for me ~1s vs > 200s for the first one 

Comment: What do `ou` and `inr` mean in your first query?

Comment: Those are aliases for the `yourTable` - `ou`= "outer" and `inr` = "inner"

Answer (score 162):

From "[Find duplicate rows with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471179/find-duplicate-rows-with-postgresql/14471928#14471928)" here's smart solution:

```
select * from (
  SELECT id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1, column2 ORDER BY id asc) AS Row
  FROM tbl
) dups
where 
dups.Row > 1
```

Comment: This is fast! Worked over millions of rows in a fraction of second. Other answers just hanged there...

Comment: As fas as I see, this query doesn't consider all rows within a group. It shows only duplicates to something, part of the duplicates will be with rownum = 1. Correct me If I wrong

Comment: @vladimir Filipchenko To have it with all lines, add a level to Alexkovelsky solution:
`SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, LEAD(row,1) OVER () AS nextrow FROM (
      SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(w) AS row
      FROM tbl
      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3)
   ) x
) y
WHERE
row > 1 OR nextrow > 1;`

Comment: @VladimirFilipchenko Just replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `COUNT(*)`, and add `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` after `ORDER BY id asc`

Comment: so much better than other solutions I've found. also works equally well for deleting dupes with `DELETE ...USING` and some minor adjustments

Comment: If you need to delete the duplicates and there is nothing distinguishing the two rows, you can include `ctid` in the inner select and then join on `ctid` in the where clause of the delete.

Answer (score 62):

In order to make it easier I assume that you wish to apply a unique constraint only for column year and the primary key is a column named id.

In order to find duplicate values you should run,

```
SELECT year, COUNT(id)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY year
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(id);
```

Using the sql statement above you get a table which contains all the duplicate years in your table. In order **to delete all the duplicates except of the the latest duplicate entry** you should use the above sql statement.

```
DELETE
FROM YOUR_TABLE A USING YOUR_TABLE_AGAIN B
WHERE A.year=B.year AND A.id<B.id;
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Can be used on a static table without a unique column by replacing `A.id<B.id` with `A.ctid<B.ctid`

Comment: is this group by necessary if you are looking for say, count(*) = 1?

Comment: this should be the right answer

Answer (score 16):

Following SQL syntax provides better performance while checking for duplicate rows.

```
SELECT id, count(id)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 9):

You can join to the same table on the fields that would be duplicated and then anti-join on the id field. Select the id field from the first table alias (tn1) and then use the array_agg function on the id field of the second table alias. Finally, for the array_agg function to work properly, you will group the results by the tn1.id field. This will produce a result set that contains the the id of a record and an array of all the id's that fit the join conditions.

```
select tn1.id,
       array_agg(tn2.id) as duplicate_entries, 
from table_name tn1 join table_name tn2 on 
    tn1.year = tn2.year 
    and tn1.sid = tn2.sid 
    and tn1.user_id = tn2.user_id 
    and tn1.cid = tn2.cid
    and tn1.id <> tn2.id
group by tn1.id;
```

Obviously, id's that will be in the duplicate_entries array for one id, will also have their own entries in the result set. You will have to use this result set to decide which id you want to become the source of 'truth.' The one record that shouldn't get deleted. Maybe you could do something like this:

```
with dupe_set as (
select tn1.id,
       array_agg(tn2.id) as duplicate_entries, 
from table_name tn1 join table_name tn2 on 
    tn1.year = tn2.year 
    and tn1.sid = tn2.sid 
    and tn1.user_id = tn2.user_id 
    and tn1.cid = tn2.cid
    and tn1.id <> tn2.id
group by tn1.id
order by tn1.id asc)
select ds.id from dupe_set ds where not exists 
 (select de from unnest(ds.duplicate_entries) as de where de < ds.id)
```

Selects the lowest number ID's that have duplicates (assuming the ID is increasing int PK). These would be the ID's that you would keep around.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Sandro Wiggers, I did something similiar to

```
WITH ordered AS ( 
  SELECT id,year, user_id, sid, cid,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year, user_id, sid, cid ORDER BY id) AS rnk 
  FROM user_links 
), 
to_delete AS ( 
  SELECT id
  FROM   ordered 
  WHERE  rnk > 1
) 
DELETE 
FROM user_links
USING to_delete 
WHERE user_link.id = to_delete.id;
```

If you want to test it, change it slightly:

```
WITH ordered AS ( 
  SELECT id,year, user_id, sid, cid,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year, user_id, sid, cid ORDER BY id) AS rnk 
  FROM user_links 
), 
to_delete AS ( 
  SELECT id,year,user_id,sid, cid
  FROM   ordered 
  WHERE  rnk > 1
) 
SELECT * FROM to_delete;
```

This will give an overview of what is going to be deleted (there is no problem to keep year,user_id,sid,cid in the to_delete query when running the deletion, but then they are not needed)

Comment: This was the most effective and accurate solution for the situation I was facing

Answer (score 2):

In your case, because of the constraint you need to delete the duplicated records.

1. Find the duplicated rows
2. Organize them by `created_at` date - in this case I'm keeping the oldest
3. Delete the records with `USING` to filter the right rows

```sql
WITH duplicated AS ( 
    SELECT id,
        count(*) 
    FROM products 
    GROUP BY id 
    HAVING count(*) > 1), 
ordered AS ( 
    SELECT p.id, 
        created_at, 
        rank() OVER (partition BY p.id ORDER BY p.created_at) AS rnk 
    FROM products o 
    JOIN     duplicated d ON d.id = p.id ), 
products_to_delete AS ( 
    SELECT id, 
        created_at 
    FROM   ordered 
    WHERE  rnk = 2
) 
DELETE 
FROM products 
USING products_to_delete 
WHERE products.id = products_to_delete.id 
    AND products.created_at = products_to_delete.created_at;
```

Comment: what is "p" in "p.id" or "p.created_at"? Should the last FROM clause be "FROM products p"?

Answer (score 2):

If values for `column1, column2` in table `mytable` should together uniquely identify a row but aren't, then you can list the duplicate columns with their count as follows:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, count(*) as ct
FROM mytable
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY ct DESC;
```

To find the original records, you can then use a join on the query above:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY column1, column2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) subquery
ON t.column1 = subquery.column1 AND t.column2 = subquery.column2;
```

To list the duplicates next to each other, append

```sql
ORDER BY t.column1, t.column2
```

to the outer query

Answer (score 0):

```
begin;
create table user_links(id serial,year bigint, user_id bigint, sid bigint, cid bigint);
insert into  user_links(year, user_id, sid, cid) values (null,null,null,null),
 (null,null,null,null), (null,null,null,null),
 (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4),
 (1,2,3,4),(1,1,3,8),
 (1,1,3,9),
 (1,null,null,null),(1,null,null,null);
commit;
```

set operation with distinct and except.

```
(select id, year, user_id, sid, cid from user_links order by 1)
except
select distinct on (year, user_id, sid, cid) id, year, user_id, sid, cid 
from user_links order by 1;
```

except all also works. Since id serial make all rows unique.

```
(select id, year, user_id, sid, cid from user_links order by 1) 
except all
select distinct on (year, user_id, sid, cid)
id, year, user_id, sid, cid  from user_links order by 1;
```

So far works nulls and non-nulls.
**delete:**

```
with a as(
(select id, year, user_id, sid, cid from user_links order by 1)
except all
select distinct on (year, user_id, sid, cid)
id, year, user_id, sid, cid  from user_links order by 1)
delete from user_links using a  where user_links.id = a.id returning *;
```