# Filter duplicate rows in Postgres based on conditions between those rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table

```
CREATE TABLE data(
 irs_number VARCHAR (50),
 mop_up INTEGER,
 ou VARCHAR (50)
);
```

How would I return *all* matching records that...

- have at least one identical value for `irs_number` in another row AND
- at least one `mop_up` of those with the same `irs_number` must be set to `1` AND
- the `ou` values are not identical, i.e. only return those not matching to a row with the identical `irs_number`.

... so that all `irs_numbers` would be returned (not only one where the conditions are true - see example below).

I tried this but the query cannot finish within reasonable time:

```
SELECT irs_number, mop_up, ou
FROM data outer_data
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
FROM data inner_data
WHERE inner_data.irs_number = outer_data.irs_number
AND inner_data.mop_up = 1 OR outer_data.mop_up = 1
AND inner_data.ou <> outer_data.ou
);
```

As well as variations of duplicate counts as described here: [How to find duplicate records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156795/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-postgresql) - they will always just return the duplicates but not the proper filter applied.

---

**edit**:

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES 
('0001', 1, 'abc'),
('0001', 0, 'abc'),
('0001', 0, 'cde'),
('0001', 0, 'abc'),
('0002', 1, 'abc'),
('0002', 0, 'abc'),
('0003', 0, 'abc'),
('0003', 0, 'xyz')
;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be28f

a query should ideally return:

```
irs_number  mop_up  ou
-----------------------
0001        1       abc
0001        0       abc
0001        0       cde
0001        0       abc
```

(order not important)
meaning it should return all rows matching having the `irs_number` with the condition above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple `exists` clause:

```
SELECT irs_number, mop_up, ou
FROM data d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM data d2
              WHERE d2.irs_number = d.irs_number AND
                    d2.mop_up = 1 AND
                    d2.ou <> d.ou
             );
```

EDIT:

The above misinterpreted the question.  It assumed that a `mop_up = 1` needed to be on a *different* `ou`.  As I read the question, this is ambiguous but doesn't appear to be what you want.  So, two `exists` address this:

```
SELECT irs_number, mop_up, ou
FROM data d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM data d2
              WHERE d2.irs_number = d.irs_number AND
                    d2.mop_up = 1
             ) AND
     EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM data d2
              WHERE d2.irs_number = d.irs_number AND
                    d2.ou <> d.ou
             );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c972a438da5d4a1a7845407cc489d939) is a db<>fiddle.

Both these solutions will be able to take advantage of an index on `(irs_number, mop_up, ou)`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the requirements of the question.

Comment: this would return only those with `mop_up` set to `1` but not all within where at least on `mop_up` was set to `1`

Comment: @dh762 . . . Not at all.  This would return all `irs_numbers` that have a corresponding row with `mop_up = 1` -- which is what you are asking for.  I have no idea why you are confusing the `where` clause in the correlated subquery with what the outer query returns.

Comment: correct, but this would only serve as a subquery because the final query should return all records with that subqueried `irs_number` - see example - your query does only return 1 row with `0001` instead of all 4 with `0001`. It might not be obvious from the pre-edit question (will update)

Comment: @dh762 . . . I see.  I interpreted the second and third bullet points differently from what you intended.  I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: this solution is 2x as fast as https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049567/1344855 on the same database

Answer (score 1):

I think this join will do:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE irs_number in (
  SELECT irs_number
  FROM data d
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM data 
    WHERE irs_number = d.irs_number
    AND (mop_up = 1 OR d.mop_up = 1)
    AND ou <> d.ou
  )
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=c7f402606fade4e19351d71d4c21e368)

Comment: it does return also rows that have just a single `irs_number` @forpas

Comment: This joins rows with the same `irs_number` and different `ou`, meaning different rows with the same `irs_number`. Can you post sample data and expected results so to be clear?

Comment: correction to the comment: it does return one row only if there are duplicate `irs_numbers` within the same `ou` (at least one has `mop_up` = true). happy to add sample data

Comment: Why should `0001  0  abc` be returned? There is not a row with the same irs_number and different ou with mop_up = 1 to any of the 2 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189610/discussion-between-dh762-and-forpas).

Comment: I think this answer is more complicated than necessary for the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff then why don't you post an answer less complicated that does solve problem?