# Is there any query to find duplicate records count corresponding to package_no column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table structure like this

```
package_no   road_name road_code
p1            r1         c1
p1            r1         c1
p2            r1         c1
```

I Need to count duplicate road code corresponding to the column package_no
I expect one record from the above table with a duplicate package p1 and  road count with 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find duplicate records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156795/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-postgresql)

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156795/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a consistency problem. In your initial description you say "duplicate road code corresponding to the column package_no", however in response to @GordonLinoff yoe indicate you want "duplicate appearance of r1". Yet "r1" corresponds to road_name. So which is it: road_Code or rode_name. Either way:

```
select t.package_no, t.road_code, count(*) - 1 "# Duplicates" 
  from test t
 group by t.package_no, t.road_code
 having count(*) > 1;
```

Just replace road_name by road_code is required.  
The query returns count - 1 as per initial requirement "p1 and road count with 1"

But what would the result be if the following also existed:

```
package_no   road_name road_code
p1            r1         c2
p1            r1         c2
p1            r2         c1
p1            r2         c1
p1            r2         c2
```

Comment: Thanks for help , second query match my requirement because one road is compulsory available to one package my concern is to count duplicate appearance of road_code to same package .

Answer (score 0):

Do you want aggregation with `count(distinct)`?

```
select package_no, count(*) as num_rows, count(distinct r1) as num_r1
from t
group by package_no
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I need to count the duplicate appearance of r1   not distinct obviously group by package_no