# Counting several repeated values in a cloumn

Tags: postgresql, count

I need to count how many times certain value occurs in a column

It looks like this (`select * from znajezyki order by klos`)

[image]

klos - is a serial number of a person (this value is repeated)

Now I need to create a query that will show me how many people knows 1,2,3 languages

If the same "klos" value is repeated 2 times that means that this person knows 2 languages if it occurs 3 times that means that pearson knows 3 languages and so on

I'd like my result to look something like this:
[image]

I tried refering to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156795/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-postgresql) but i cannot understand it and can't get it to work

I hope y'all can understand what I am talking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do the simple thing: count how many languages each person knows

```
SELECT klos, COUNT(*) AS langs
FROM znajezyki
GROUP BY klos
```

Then use that result in a subquery to count the people by how many languages they know:

```
SELECT langs, COUNT(*) AS persons
FROM (
  SELECT klos, COUNT(*) AS langs
  FROM znajezyki
  GROUP BY klos
) AS temp
GROUP BY langs
```