# Postgresql : How to update one field for all duplicate values based at the end of the string of a field except one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98ea/1   (Sample Table)

I have a table with the following fields:

1. transfer_id
2. src_path
3. DH_USER_ID
4. email
5. status_state
6. ip_address

src_path field contains a couple of duplicates filename values but a different folder name at the beginning of the string.

Example:

1. 191915/**NequeVestibulumEget.mp3**
2. /191918/**NequeVestibulumEget.mp3**
3. 191920/**NequeVestibulumEget.mp3**

I am trying to do the following:

1. Set status_state field to 'canceled' for all the duplicate filenames within (src_path) field except for one.

I want the results to look like this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e65f/2

*I apologize in advance for being a complete noob, but I am taking SQL at college and I need help.

Comment: Hi again Rudy. The second row start with a `/` is that ok or is a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find duplicate rows with PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471179/find-duplicate-rows-with-postgresql)

Comment: Eliminating duplicates is a popular task. You didn't show what you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried several usuals examples. But since src_path contains a different path at the beginning of the string, I am lost on how to either pass that to a variable or sorted based on the duplicate of the filenames. So far, I have select  substring(src_path, '[^\\//]*$') from priority_transfer; to only give me filenames (without the slash)

Comment: @JakubKania Even when is similar. The duplicated part have to be calculate first before use the normal process.

Comment: In your fiddle looks like all duplicate filename are group by `transfer_id` is that always the case? even when src_pth is different

Comment: sorry, that WAS a typo on the random data generator website. Transfer_id should be incremental.  I updated the fiddle to reflect this change. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98ea/1

Comment: what about filename `\Sollicitudin.mp3` is ` \ ` allow as part of the filename ?

Comment: Yes it could be either slash \ or /.

Comment: Well that is very weird. That should be some validation on the input to update that.

Comment: Basically, the example says that src_path gets updated based on the uploader's OS. If windows then "C:\somepath\filename.mov, if Linux then "/home/user/filename.mov"

Comment: Your want all dup set to `canceled` what about the original? doesnt matter or one should have `pending` ?? In your case that file name have `pending` and `queued` .... Also if no dup, we dont change status?

Comment: I want to leave one untouched and the rest set to canceled. It doesn't matter the status, I just need to set all dups to canceled except one.  If no dups, then leave status the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b98ea/16)

- fix_os_name: Fix the windows path string to unix format.
- file_name: Split the path using `/`, and use `char_length` to bring last split.
- drank: Create a seq for each filename. So unique filename only have `1`, but dup also have `2,3 ...`
- UPDATE: check if that row have rn > 1 mean is a dup.

.

Take note the color highlight is wrong, but code runs ok.

```sql
with fix_os_name as (
    SELECT transfer_id, replace(src_path,'\','/') src_path, 
    DH_USER_ID, email, status_state, ip_address
    FROM priority_transfer p
),  
file_name as (
    SELECT 
       fon.*,
       split_part(src_path,
                  '/',
                  char_length(src_path) - char_length(replace(src_path,'/','')) + 1
                 ) sfile
    FROM fix_os_name fon
), 
drank as (
    SELECT 
        f.*,
        row_number() over (partition by sfile order by sfile) rn
    from file_name f
)
UPDATE priority_transfer p
SET status_state = 'canceled'
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM drank d
               WHERE d.transfer_id = p.transfer_id
               AND  d.rn > 1);
```

**ADD:** One row is untouch

[image]

Comment: It works great!!... However, query is updating status_state to 'canceled' for all dups. I need at least one record to leave untouched. Any thoughts? I'll see if I can come up with an answer too.

Comment: Please check the picture I add one row is untouched.

Comment: Awesome, I fixed the issue. It works flawlessly... Error on my side since both rows had the same transfer_id.

Comment: Good this work for you. But please next time try to work a litle more in making the question with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexp_matches function to separate the file name from the directory. 
From there you can use distinct() to build a table with unique values for the filename.

```
select
regexp_matches(src_path, '[a-zA-Z.0-9]*$') , *
from priority_transfer
;
```

Comment: You should try your query in the fiddle. As you can see there is window and unix folders.

Comment: You are correct @JuanCarlosOropeza, I didn't see this before. 
Modified the query, so that it gets all the file names now, regardless of win or unix folders... thnx!

Comment: Sorry pat still doesnt work. You need remove the folder portion and leave the remaing filename after '\' or '/' sometimes doesnt have folder. Let me know if you can work a regexp, i have to convert all '\' to '/' and then split by '/'

Comment: How about select regexp_matches(src_path, '[^\\//]*$')  from priority_transfer;   ?

Comment: select substring(src_path, '[^\\//]*$') from priority_transfer;      ....Only gives me filenames after either / or \

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that's strange. When I run the query in Fiddle it catches all of the file names... 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5e65f/17/0

Comment: Dont ask me. Im only know basic regexp, and i already tell pabtorre his solution didnt work,.