# How to find duplicate records and update using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-update

| id | userid | deviceid | isactive | last_modified (timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | fdghfgh | true | 2021-02-12 |
| 2 | 12 | sdsdfg | true | 2021-02-14 |
| 3 | 5 | fghfgh | true | 2021-01-12 |
| 4 | 15 | dffdg | true | 2021-02-14 |
| 5 | 15 | dofghfjdog | true | 2021-01-09 |

Only one device should be active for a user. Above table user 12 and 15 having two active devices.

How to set the recently modified device as active and other devices as false (for the corresponding user) in postgresql query?

Result should be:

| id | userid | deviceid | isactive | last_modified (timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | fdghfgh | false | 2021-02-12 |
| 2 | 12 | sdsdfg | true | 2021-02-14 |
| 3 | 5 | fghfgh | true | 2021-01-12 |
| 4 | 15 | dffdg | true | 2021-02-14 |
| 5 | 15 | dofghfjdog | false | 2021-01-09 |

Comment: What query do you have so far? And why did you not just [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191293/how-to-find-duplicate-records-in-same-table-postgresql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql : How to update one field for all duplicate values based at the end of the string of a field except one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403487/postgresql-how-to-update-one-field-for-all-duplicate-values-based-at-the-end-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RANK () OVER function like below

which will give you each entry ranked based on last modified date for each userid group.

Then you can write update query to update isactive to false where device_rank ! =1

```
select id,userid,deviceid,isactive,last_modified,
RANK () OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY userid
        ORDER BY last_modified DESC
    ) device_rank 
from deviceTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Query 1: (to rank the devices by last_modified_time)

```
select id,userid,deviceid,isactive,last_modified_timestamp,
RANK () OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY last_modified_timestamp DESC
    ) device_rank 
from myschema.mytable rankTable
```

Query 2: (to update the device table to make only one active device - recent device)

```
UPDATE myschema.mytable ud
SET is_active = false
FROM (select id,userid,deviceid,isactive,last_modified_timestamp,
RANK () OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY last_modified_timestamp DESC
    ) device_rank 
from myschema.mytable) as rankTable
WHERE ud.id=rankTable.id and rankTable.device_rank != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *set* the values, then use `update`.  The subquery is used to calculate the date that should be considered active:

```
update t
    set is_active = (last_modified = max_lst_modified)
    from (select user_id, max(last_modified) as max_last_modified
          from t
          group by user_id
         ) tt
    where tt.user_id = t.user_id;
```