# Select duplicate records with error message while querying on UNION ALL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, error_msg FROM table_name1
WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, error_msg FROM table_name2
WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, error_msg FROM table_name3
WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
```

For the above query the output will look below

```
_id, col1, col2, jobid, error_msg
1, "Hi", "Hel", 1, "Data Invalid"
1, "Hi1", "Hel", 2, ""
2, "Hello", "DupTest",3, "" 
3, "Nota Dup", "All is Good",3 ,""
```

---

I need to raise error message if there is duplicates , for the above case _id (1) need to select error message as "Duplicate Entries Present"

My solution looks below

```
WITH tmp AS
(
  SELECT _id , count(1) as cnt FROM
  (
    SELECT _id FROM table_name1
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id FROM table_name2
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id FROM table_name3
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3) 
   )
   GROUP BY _id
)
SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, 
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name1
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name2
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
    WHERE tn2.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name3
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
    WHERE tn3.jobid in (1,2,3)
```

Could you suggest is there better solution than this?

Possible one more option create it as View to use it on multiple places

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW tmp AS 
SELECT _id , count(1) as cnt FROM
      (
        SELECT _id FROM table_name1
        WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT _id FROM table_name2
        WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT _id FROM table_name3
        WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3) 
       )
       GROUP BY _id
```

Comment: What I have done bad ? why negative for my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function:

```
with cte as(SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, error_msg FROM table_name1
            WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT _id, col1, col2,jobid, error_msg FROM table_name2
            WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT _id, col1, col2,jobid, error_msg FROM table_name3
            WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3))

select *, CASE WHEN count(*) over(partition by _id) > 1 
               THEN CONCAT_WS(',' , cte.error_msg, "Dup present")
               ELSE cte.error_msg
from cte
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think what if the case "cte" table has some other error message, we need to concat those error messages too. But I didn't mention about it in the question though

Answer (score 0):

Window function solution , Credit goes to
[Find duplicate rows with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471179/find-duplicate-rows-with-postgresql)

```
WITH tmp AS
(
  SELECT _id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY _id) AS cnt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT _id FROM table_name1
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id FROM table_name2
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id FROM table_name3
    WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3) 
   )

)
SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid, 
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name1
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
WHERE tn1.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name2
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
    WHERE tn2.jobid in (1,2,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _id, col1, col2, jobid
CASE WHEN tmp.cnt > 1 THEN "Dup present" ELSE NULL as error_msg
FROM table_name3
JOIN tmp USING(_id)
    WHERE tn3.jobid in (1,2,3)
```