# Select only those records which are twice in postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
select distinct(msg_id),sub_id from programs where sub_id IN
(
select sub_id from programs group by sub_id having count(sub_id) = 2 limit 5
)
```

sub_id means subscriberID

Inner query will return those subscriberID which are exactly 2 times in the program table and main query will gives those subscriberID which having distinct msg_id.

This result will generated

```
msg_id  sub_id
------|--------|
 112  |  313
 111  |  222
 113  |  313
 115  |  112
 116  |  112
 117  |  101
 118  |  115
 119  |  115
 110  |  222
```

I want it should be

```
    msg_id  sub_id
    ------|--------|
     112  |  313
     111  |  222
     113  |  313
     115  |  112
     116  |  112
     118  |  115
     119  |  115
     110  |  222
```

117  |  101  (this result should not be in output because its only once)

I want only those record which are twice.

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: I already posted data which I got from the query. What you want other than this ?

Comment: You posted the output of your query. Post the input data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate rows with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471179/find-duplicate-rows-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but are you just missing the second field in your in-list?

```
select distinct msg_id, sub_id, <presumably other fields>
from programs
where (sub_id, msg_id) IN
(
  select sub_id, msg_id
  from programs
  group by sub_id, msg_id
  having count(sub_id) = 2
)
```

If so, you can also do this with a windowing function:

```
with cte as (
  select
    msg_id, sub_id, <presumably other fields>,
    count (*) over (partition by msg_id, sub_id) as cnt
  from programs
)
select distinct
  msg_id, sub_id, <presumably other fields>
from cte
where cnt = 2
```

Comment: No, its not working. I think question is not much clear to you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT msg_id, MAX(sub_id)
FROM programs 
GROUP BY msg_id
HAVING COUNT(sub_id) = 2  -- COUNT(sub_id) > 1 if you want all those that repeat more than once
ORDER BY msg_id
```