# Improve performance of query with union in from clause subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, union

How might I improve the performance of this query? I have an index on c1 and there is no primary key by choice on tb1. My goal is to create a record for each instance of c3.

```
select 
t1.*

into tb2

from (
select 
c1,
c2,
c3
from tb1
where c1 = '1'

union

select 
c1,
c2,
c4
from tb1
where c1 = '1'
) as t1
where t1.c3 != ''
```

Table definition (PG v9.0):

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
  c1 text
  c2 text
  c3 text
  c4 text
);
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX c1_idx   ON tb1 USING btree (c1);
```

Comment: Please always include table definitions and your version of Postgres for performance optimization questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tb2 AS 
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM   tb1
WHERE  c1 = '1'
AND    c3 <> ''

UNION ALL
SELECT c1, c2, c4
FROM   tb1
WHERE  c1 = '1'
AND    c4 <> '';
```

- Use `UNION ALL` unless you want to eliminate possible duplicates. Faster. The result is different if duplicates occur!
- No need for a subquery.
- Use `CREATE TABLE AS` instead of `SELECT INTO`. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html):

> This command is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`, but it is
>   preferred since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of
>   the SELECT INTO syntax. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS` offers a superset
>   of the functionality offered by `SELECT INTO`.

- The single quotes around `'1'` indicate you are storing numeric data as string type. If so, that's not good. Consider [appropriate data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html) ...

#### Alternative with CTE

If the table is big, this alternative with a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) will be probably be faster, since we only read once from it.

Also including additional requests from comment, add column, add pk:

```
CREATE TABLE tb2 AS 
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
   FROM   tb1
   WHERE  c1 = '1'
   AND   (c3 <> '' OR c4 <> '')
   )
SELECT c1, c2, c3, NULL::text AS new_column  -- add new column
FROM   cte
WHERE  c3 <> ''

UNION ALL
SELECT c1, c2, c4, NULL
FROM   cte
WHERE  c4 <> '';

-- add primary key:
ALTER TABLE tb2 ADD CONSTRAINT tb2_pkey PRIMARY KEY(???);
```

If the table is big, you might want to increase [`temp_buffers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-TEMP-BUFFERS) setting (for the session only). More info in this related answer:
[How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries/8826879#8826879)

If you need to run this often (and don't mind the small penalty on write opertaions), and if you can define a superset of rows that eliminates large parts of the rest, I would suggest a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) ...

Comment: Excellent! I will report results. All columns are text as the table is denormailized.

Comment: @swhit: Depending on *exact* requirements, there might be more options ... I added a few more pointers.

Comment: I like the alternative with a CTE. However, I have a further requirement that I thought would have little impact. I need to add a primary key column and two additional columns to the resulting table. Thanks so much.

Comment: I can probably add the additional columns to the CTE?

Comment: @swhit: Depends where the columns come from. Or just new, empty columns? Your information is lacking. I added yet more to my answer. For new requirements start a *new question*. You can always reference this one for context.

Comment: The cost of the CTE query is ~15 million vs ~6 million for the select into. :(

Comment: Every union does a CTE scan with the full amount of records.

Comment: CREATE TABLE AS results in approximately the same cost as SELECT INTO.

Comment: I added an index for each c(n) <> '' and it reduced it to apprx. 1.5 million.

Comment: @swhit: 1) 2x full CTE scan is to be expected. CTE scan != seq. table scan. 2) There is no performance difference between `CREATE TABLE AS` and `SELECT INTO`. The former is just better form. 3) Partial index, horray! :)