# Deleting while using "having" in the query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have the following SQL query that returns duplicates of emails

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
```

In the case above, how can we actually delete those duplicate rows? or only one of the duplicates so they are no longer duplicates?

Comment: Assuming your primary key is a `user` how would you identify which `user` you would want to delete of the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 3):

One method uses `ctid`:

```
delete from users
    where ctid not in (select min(ctid)
                       from users
                       group by email
                      );
```

This deletes all but one row for each email.  `ctid` is an internal row identifier.  It would be better to use a user-defined primary key column.

Comment: *`delete from users`

Comment: @Abelisto . . . I don't see how it would do that.

Comment: @Abelisto . . . This should delete all rows but one for each email.

Answer (score 2):

This method below will allow you to remove the records from your table even if you don't have a primary key or unique identifier.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email) AS RN
FROM users
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```