# postgres - select with "using"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I found a very useful delete query that will delete duplicates based on specific columns:

```
DELETE FROM table USING table alias 
  WHERE table.field1 = alias.field1 AND table.field2 = alias.field2 AND
    table.max_field < alias.max_field
```

[How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries)

However, is there an equivalent **SELECT** query that will allow to filter the same way? Was trying **USING** but no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` your table with itself using the specific columns, `field1` and `field2`, and then filter based on a comparison between `max_field` on both tables.

```
select t1.*
from mytable t1
  join mytable t2 on (t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2)
where t1.max_field < t2.max_field;
```

You will get all the duplicates whose max_field is not the greatest.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0bd32/1) here.